# How to generate new table related code in existing Ria Service without deleting it

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

How to generate new table related code in existing Ria Service without deleting it. Please Suggest best Practice.
I am having one domain service. I have modified lot of auto generated code and meta data. Now I want to include couple of more tables auto generated code without deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to add a second, temporary doamian service that includes those tables and then copy the code over to the existing domain service. Remove the temporary domain service once you are finished.

The other option is to hand craft the new code. Use the existing code for the other tables as an example.

My understanding is that the generator is only intended to be used for the creation of new domain services.